# Memory leaks on React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-functional-component

I have a MERN stack application (a reddit clone) which is composed of many subcomponents. One of these is the side menu which has all the subcategories listed. I am new to React and am faced with a memory leak issue and I can't figure out where the memory leak is coming from. Can anyone lead me to a better understanding of why there is such issue in the code below? Thank you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PostServices from "../../services/posts";
import {
  SidebarContainer,
  Button,
  CategoriesBar,
  Category,
  CategoryLastRow
} from "./styles";

function Sidebar(props) {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCategories() {
      const APIcall = await PostServices.getCategories();
      const categories = APIcall.data.categories;
      setCategories(categories);

      if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
        setLoggedIn(true);
      }
    }

    getCategories();
  }, [])

  return (
    <SidebarContainer>
      { loggedIn ? <Button>CREATE A NEW THREAD</Button> : null }
      
      <CategoriesBar>
        <span className="bold-text">CATEGORIES</span>
        
        { categories.map((category, index) => {
            if (index === categories.length - 1) {
              return (
                <Link key={index} to={`/categories/${category}`} style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                  <CategoryLastRow>
                    <span>r/{category}</span>
                  </CategoryLastRow>
                </Link>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Link key={index} to={`/categories/${category}`} style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
                  <Category>
                    <span>r/{category}</span>
                  </Category>
                </Link>
              )
            }
          })
        }
      </CategoriesBar>
    </SidebarContainer>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: How have you determined that you are leaking memory?

Comment: The browser popped out the usual warning pointing to this component. I tried rewriting the code to the best of my ability but to no avail. Maybe I understood something incorrectly.